# Prove that $K(x_{1},x_{2})=f(x_{1})K_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})f(x_{2})$ is symmetric positive definite if $K_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})$ is symmetric positive definite

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, kernel-trick, functional-data-analysis

I have been trying to prove this 5th proposition on the 25th [slide](https://www.haralick.org/ML/kernel_trick.pdf)

We can prove that $ K(x_{1},x_{2}) $ will be a valid kernel as:
\begin{align}
 K(x_{1},x_{2}) = & \; f(x_{1})K_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})f(x_{2}) \\ 
= & \; f(x_{1})\langle\phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{2})\rangle f(x_{2}) \\ 
= & \; \langle f(x_{1})\phi(x_{1}),f(x_{2})\phi(x_{2})\rangle \\  
= & \; \langle \phi^{'}(x_{1}),\phi^{'}(x_{2}) \rangle
\end{align}

This way we can prove the first part. Now how to prove that it is also symmetric positive definite?

\begin{align}
 c^{T}\langle \phi^{'}(x_{1}),\phi^{'}(x_{2}) \rangle \,   = & \; \sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1} c_{i} c_{j} \langle \phi^{'}(x_{i}),\phi^{'}(x_{j}) \rangle \\
= & \;  \sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1} \langle c_{i} \phi^{'}(x_{i}), c_{j}\phi^{'}(x_{j}) \rangle \\ 
= & \;  \langle \sum_{i=1} c_{i} \phi^{'}(x_{i}), \sum_{j=1} c_{j}\phi^{'}(x_{j}) \rangle \\
= & \; \| \sum_{i=1} c_{i} \phi^{'}(x_{i}) \|^{2} \geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: What definitions or characterizations of symmetric pd kernels do you know? A direct application of any of them ought to do the job.

Comment: @whuber does it look better now?